# Accumulate items in a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have a list of tuples that looks like this:

```
lst = [(0, 0), (2, 3), (4, 3), (5, 1)]
```

What is the best way to accumulate the sum of the first and secound tuple elements? Using the example above, I'm looking for the best way to produce this list:

```
new_lst = [(0, 0), (2, 3), (6, 6), (11, 7)]
```

I am looking for a solution in Python 2.6

Comment: If you only want the last tuple use `reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]), lst, (0, 0))`

Comment: No, I want the entire list, not just the last element. Please see the example I provided.

Comment: Just for reference: this would be the haskell implementation: `acc = scanl1 (\acc x -> (fst x + fst acc, snd x + snd acc))`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would argue the best solution is [`itertools.accumulate()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to accumulate the values, and using [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to split up your columns and merge them back. This means the generator just handles a single column, and makes the method entirely scalable.

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> lst = [(0, 0), (2, 3), (4, 3), (5, 1)]
>>> list(zip(*map(accumulate, zip(*lst))))
[(0, 0), (2, 3), (6, 6), (11, 7)]
```

We use `zip()` to take the columns, then apply `itertools.accumulate()` to each column, then use `zip()` to merge them back into the original format.

This method will work for any iterable, not just sequences, and should be relatively efficient.

Prior to 3.2, accumulate can be defined as:

```
def accumulate(iterator):
    total = 0
    for item in iterator:
        total += item
        yield total
```

(The docs page gives a more generic implementation, but for this use case, we can use this simple implementation).

Comment: If you're using `itertools` anyway, why not use `izip` and `imap` as well?

Comment: @ThijsvanDien Because `itertools.accumulate()` only exists in 3.2+, and in 3.x, `izip()` and `imap()` don't exist (`zip()` and `map()` are generators in 3.x, so they would be redundant).

Comment: That's really handy. I didn't realize that `itertools.accumulate` existed. I've probably written my own accumulator functions half a dozen times.

Comment: @Blckknght I only just realized while I was writing this answer. It's a pretty recent addition, and yeah, it's a useful little one.

Answer (score 3):

How about this generator:

```
def accumulate_tuples(iterable):
    accum_a = accum_b = 0
    for a, b in iterable:
        accum_a += a
        accum_b += b
        yield accum_a, accum_b
```

If you need a list, just call `list(accumulate_tuples(your_list))`.

Here's a version that works for arbitrary length tuples:

```
def accumulate_tuples(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable):
    accum = next(it) # initialize with the first value
    yield accum
    for val in it: # iterate over the rest of the values
        accum = tuple(a+b for a, b in zip(accum, val))
        yield accum
```

Comment: It always surprises me that python don't have a readable 1 line solution for such things.

Comment: @Elazar It's not exactly a super-common use case. There is no point cluttering up the stdlib with stuff people will rarely ever use. That said, my answer is a one liner in 3.2+.

Answer (score 2):

```
>> reduce(lambda x,y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]), lst)
 (11, 7)
```

**EDIT.** I can see your updated question. To get the running list you can do:

```
>> [reduce(lambda x,y: (x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]), lst[:i]) for i in range(1,len(lst)+1)]
[(0, 0), (2, 3), (6, 6), (11, 7)]
```

Not super efficient, but at least it works and does what you want :)

Comment: No, I want the entire list, not just the last element. Please see the example I provided.

Comment: I didn't see that example at beginning, did you add it later? Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This works for any length of `tuple`s or other `iterable`s.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def accumulate(lst):
    sums = defaultdict(int)
    for item in lst:
        for index, subitem in enumerate(item):
            sums[index] += subitem
        yield [sums[index] for index in xrange(len(sums))]

print [tuple(x) for x in accumulate([(0, 0), (2, 3), (4, 3), (5, 1)])]
```

In Python 2.7+ you would use a `Counter` instead of `defaultdict(int)`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this works. Does it rely on dictionaries with integer keys being iterated in key order? That seems risky (I think it's an implementation detail).

Answer (score 1):

This is a really poor way (in terms of performance) to do this because `list.append` is expensive, but it works.

```
last = lst[0]
new_list = [last]
for t in lst[1:]:
    last += t
    new_list.append(last)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function

```
>>> def my_accumulate(lst):
      new_lst = [lst[0]]
      for x, y in lst[1:]:
        new_lst.append((new_lst[-1][0]+x, new_lst[-1][1]+y))
      return new_lst

>>> lst = [(0, 0), (2, 3), (4, 3), (5, 1)]
>>> my_accumulate(lst)
[(0, 0), (2, 3), (6, 6), (11, 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple method:

```
>> x = [(0, 0), (2, 3), (4, 3), (5, 1)]
>>> [(sum(a for a,b in x[:t] ),sum(b for a,b in x[:t])) for t in range(1,len(x)+1)]
[(0, 0), (2, 3), (6, 6), (11, 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [(0, 0), (2, 3), (4, 3), (5, 1)]

lst2 = [lst[0]]
for idx in range(1, len(lst)):
    newItem = [0,0]
    for idx2 in range(0, idx + 1):
        newItem[0] = newItem[0] + lst[idx2][0]
        newItem[1] = newItem[1] + lst[idx2][1]
    lst2.append(newItem)

print(lst2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed my code to a terser version:

```
lst = [(0, 0), (2, 3), (4, 3), (5, 1)]

def accumulate(the_list):
    the_item = iter(the_list)
    accumulator = next(the_item)
    while True:
        yield accumulator
        accumulator = tuple(x+y for (x,y) in zip (accumulator, next(the_item)))

new_lst = list(accumulate(lst))
```